# Dynamic markers for Metaio

Tags: augmented-reality, metaio

I would like to have several logos in my application that are recognized as markers and trigger some sort of event, unique per logo. From time to time I want to update these logos/markers. I don't want to use metaio cloud, I want to somehow make the app call a webservice from my server application and download new markers/logos.

Is this possible? can you point me in the right direction as far as data formats etc..

Answer (score 0):

It should still be possible to draw content from your own private FTP. Something along these lines:

https://dev.metaio.com/creator/advancedmore-information/connect-your-own-ftp/

Answer (score 0):

yes,it is possible

1)by webservice u can download images(give same name to images which u define in your assets,on webserver)
-and download this images in your assets folder
like 
File SDCardRoot = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/Assets1";

and in main activity write like this
AssetsManager.extractAllAssets(getApplicationContext(), **false**);

make flag false so previous images not overloaded,and it will keep ur download images

2)after download complete u need again to load trackingconfig